# When I set overflow-y:hidden to element causes scroll reveal animation to not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollreveal.js

I am using scrollreveal.min.js on my WordPress site.

Scroll reveal works just fine, but when I attempted to hide the vertical scroll bar that appears during animation (for the section) with

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

the scroll bar was hidden for the element, but animation on scroll no longer worked for each item.

Also, one other question, in order for overflow-y:hidden; to work I have to comment out my overflow:auto; is this necessary or is there a way those can work together?

Answer (score 0):

Overflow-y:hidden as per w3 schools "The content is clipped - and no scrolling mechanism is provided". This means that the content is cut off, as in, you can't scroll anymore. Kind of like an image when it's cropped, you can't scroll in a cropped image. You'll want something like this instead: [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)